# removing string=number from a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to understand some printouts of the alsa mixer and to compare with other values. I have the printout of alsa mixer:

```
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 codec_in0 Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 codec_in1 Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 sprot_loop_in Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 media_loop1_in Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 media_loop2_in Switch'
```

I want to remove the numid=X, i.e. I want the following output:

```
iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 codec_in0 Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 codec_in1 Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 sprot_loop_in Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 media_loop1_in Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
iface=MIXER,name='codec_out1 mix 0 media_loop2_in Switch'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed should do:

```
sed 's/numid=[0-9][0-9]*,//g' file
```

Removes `numid=any number`